# is there any way that can offset from specific record when using scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, offset

i have a lot of methods that look for records after specific active record.  examples are:

```
def photo_recent
    offsetphoto = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photos = Photo.recent.where('created_at> ?', offsetphoto.id).limit(10)#recent is a scope using created_at
end

def photo_recent
    offsetphoto = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photos = Photo.popular.where('like_count > ?', offsetphoto.like_count).limit(10)#popular is a scope using like_count
end
```

i was wondering if there is any way to modularize this such as:

```
@photos = Photo.recent.offset(Photo.find(params[:id])).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# models/photo.rb
scope :most_recent_starting_from, -> (photo) { order(created_at: :asc).where('created_at >= ?', photo.created_at) }
```

### Example Usage

```
photo = Photo.find(123)
ten_next_created_photos_after_photo = Photo.most_recent_starting_from(photo).limit(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a scope that just takes everything from the current `Photo`

```
scope :offset_from, -> (photo) { where('id >= ?', photo.id) }

Photo.offset_from(Photo.find(params[:id]))......
```